# Hiding Important Data

Tags: c#

just want to ask what would be the best way to hide sensitive data (ftp accounts, database connectionstring, etc) in .Net desktop applications.. any suggestions please.. :)

i was aware of putting data in the application and got in mind that what if the application will be deobfuscated or decompiled the hidden data will be expose.

i tried using Application Settings

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString = theConString;
```

but still the data can be seend when decompiled.

any suggestions please.

Comment: You can't really do that. If the application can access the data, so can anyone who runs it. If you want to hide some sensitive data, don't put them in the application at all.

Comment: @svick's point is an important one- who are you protecting against?  If you are trying to prevent a determined end-user of your application from being able to see them, then there is probably no way of having them stored in the application at all.  That said, there **are** ways of storing them securely, to prevent unauthorized users (like viruses, for ex) on the end-users PC from reading them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **encrypt all or part of the app.config file**. This is particularly common for protecting database connection strings.

Here is a [detailed article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx) about how to to this. In a nutshell, here is the code from there for encrypting the connection string section in app.config:

```
static void ToggleConfigEncryption(string exeConfigName)
{
    // Takes the executable file name without the
    // .config extension.
    try
    {
        // Open the configuration file and retrieve 
        // the connectionStrings section.
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.
            OpenExeConfiguration(exeConfigName);

        ConnectionStringsSection section =
            config.GetSection("connectionStrings")
            as ConnectionStringsSection;

        if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            // Remove encryption.
            section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
        }
        else
        {
            // Encrypt the section.
            section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(
                "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
        }
        // Save the current configuration.
        config.Save();

        Console.WriteLine("Protected={0}",
            section.SectionInformation.IsProtected);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```