# Is it really impossible for someone to read the connection string when it is protected?

Tags: c#, encryption, ftp, obfuscation, sensitive-data

I just saw this article [Hiding Important Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269735/hiding-important-data)

I'm thinking to use app.config for protecting my FTP connection string as it's stated in the link above but I'm wondering whether It's really impossible or not for someone to discover the ftp connection string somehow, by de-compiling, or by using other reverse engineering tools

The data contained in the software is very sensitive and shouldn't be shared with users, Could someone please help me whether I'm in the right way ?

Comment: if you really want to protect it, use windows authentication instead

Answer (score 0):

If you store a value in your App.Config then that value is not hard-coded or otherwise stored in any compiled code - it's read from your config files at runtime. As such, it cannot be retrieved *directly* by decompiling, though there is always the possibility that your application could be recompiled to spit out a string post-decryption or similar. Obviously, config values are easily accessible to anyone who has access to your application server because they can simply read your App.Config. That is, of course, unless it's encrypted as suggested in the answers to the question you've linked.